# I want to save dynamic data when moving to another page

Tags: jquery, json, django

I want to save dynamic data when moving to another page. What you are doing is drawing a graph on the canvas, and if you want to save the node and edge information in the canvas and write it out when you want, what method should you use?

I use Django, Python, PHP, jQuery, etc. I use diagram-builder in Alloy-UI, I want save this canvas Data.

```html
<div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_770" class="diagram-node-task yui3-widget yui3-overlay diagram-node yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-stacked diagram-node-selected diagram-node-focused" tabindex="1" data-nodeid="diagramNode_field_task780" style="height: 70px; width: 70px; left: 132px; top: 124px; z-index: 100;">
  <div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_772" class="diagram-node-content yui3-widget-stdmod yui3-widget-content-expanded">
    <div class="yui3-widget-bd" style="height: 70px;" id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_987">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 70px; height: 70px;" id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_986">
        <svg:svg pointer-events="none" overflow="auto" id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_855" width="77" height="77" viewBox="-7 -7 77 77" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; left: -7px; overflow: auto; visibility: visible; width: 77px; height: 77px;">
          <svg:rect id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_859" pointer-events="visiblePainted" shape-rendering="auto" width="55" height="55" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="none" stroke="transparent" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="7" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,8,8)" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="yui3-shape yui3-svgShape yui3-rect yui3-svgRect diagram-node-shape-boundary">
          </svg:rect>
        </svg:svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="diagram-node-label">task780</div>
  <div class="diagram-builder-controls">
    <div id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1557380115692_950" class="btn-toolbar-content yui3-widget component btn-toolbar">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
```

I want save node data, and load this data another page.

Comment: you can assign the date to a session or cookie variables and use them in the next page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Post the data first to any endpoint, save the data, then go to the next page and load that data.
- Pass the data to the next page trought GET parameters, if you can.

Comment: yes, or you can pass it through a POST into a view and then render another page with these parameters withouth saving them in a database.